# comparing CNN vs other classification methods

Tags: classification, conv-neural-network, methodology

I working on a classification problem.
I have created Python code that takes certain labelled input data. This is then converted into two 2 dimensional arrays. The first array is an input array of dimension NxM, where N is the number of data samples. Each row implies input condition. The second array is an output array of dimension 1xK (single row and K columns). Only one bit is set for any of the input conditions.
Using this data, I have trained a CNN. Based on the trained model, I then use independent data in order to validate if my trained model is able to predict properly. I get good accuracy of about 90%.

**Questions:**

1. I would like to know other than CNN, what other machine learning
   method I can use. I want to compare how CNN performs vs other
   classification methods for the problem I am working on.
2. Secondly, do I need to make any data modifications in order to do
   this.

Comment: I proposed an edit to your question to make it better readable. Please have a look at the [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for future reference.